# How should I return the result of a binary-operation function in a C library?

Tags: c, performance, memory-management

I'm working on a C library, and part of it deals with some mathematical types and manipulating them. Each type has a factory constructor/destructor function that allocates and frees them dynamically. For example:

```
/* Example type, but illustrates situation very well. */
typdef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Vector3D;

/* Constructor */
Vector* Vector3D_new(float x, float y, float z) {
     Vector3D* vector = (Vector3D*) malloc(sizeof(Vector3D));
     /* Initialization code here...*/

     return vector;
}

/* Destructor */
void Vector3D_destroy(Vector3D* vector) {
    free(vector);
}
```

Nice & simple, and also alleviates the loads of proper initialization for a user.

Now my main concern is how to handle functions that operate upon these types (specifically how to return the result values.) Almost every binary operation will result in a new instance of the same type, and therefore, I need to consider how to give this back to the user. I could just return things by *value*, but passing around pointers would be preferred, since it is faster, compatible with the construct/destructor methods, and doesn't leave as much burden on the user.

Currently I have it implemented by having functions dynamically allocate the result, and then return a pointer to it:

```
/* Perform an operation, and dynamically return resultant vector */
Vector3D* addVectors(Vector3D* a, Vector3D* b) {
    Vector3D* c = Vector3D_new(
        a->x + b->x,
        a->y + b->y,
        a->z + b->z);

    return c; 
}
```

By returning the value directly to the user, it has the advantage of being able to be *chained* (e.g. to be passed directly into another function as a parameter), such as:

```
/* Given three Vector3D*s : a, b, & c */
float dot = dotProduct(crossProduct(a, addVectors(b, c));
```

But given the current method, this would result in a memory leak, since the result of `addVectors()` would be passed directly to `crossProduct()`, and the user wouldn't have a chance to `free()` it (and the same thing with `crossProduct()`'s result that is passed into `dotProduct()`). To make this work, a person would have to make a pointer to hold the value(s), use that, and then `free()` it via said pointer.

```
Vector3D* d = addVectors(b, c);
Vector3D* e = crossProduct(a, d);
float dot = dotProduct(e);

Vector3D_destroy(d);
Vector3d_destroy(e);
```

This works but is much less intuitive, and loses the chaining effect I so desire.

Another possibility is to have the operation functions take 3 arguments; two for the operands, and one to store the result in, but again not very intuitive.

My question is then: What are some *elegant* & *productive*  ways of working with dynamic memory in binary operations? As a bonus, a solution that has been used in a real world library would be pretty cool. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Passing a parameter for the result is what GMP does. One unintuitive way to get chainability and getting hold of the memory is to do both, pass in a paramter for the result and return the pointer, `thing *thingnew(..., thing **handle) { /* create thing */; *handle = newthing; return newthing; }`. I'm sure there will be good reasons against this, though.

Comment: Why are you enforcing heap allocation? Return the struct itself and you'll be fine.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to write Java code in C. You should make all your functions pass the struct around rather than pointers as it is not such a big complicated struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the struct I used here was only an example. In reality the types that need to be returned could be much larger and heavier. On top of that, they could be used in fairly complex (e.g. _compound_) operations and in tight loops. It feels like overkill, especially since older-hardware is also part of my targeted audience.

Comment: I would also tend towards not forcing heap allocation as this can be much slower than stack allocation. So if you are looping through something and doing a ton of these operations that could be a huge ding in performance.

Comment: @Justin  After some basic perfomance tests, I now see what you mean. I'm now leaning more towards a stack based soloution, but I still have one concern: the possibility of a stackoverflow. I don't know how complex (e.g. deep and compounded) the operations in my library will get, nor how complex the user's will be, and given types that are heavy enough, this could be a critical factor, especially on systems where stack sizes are (potentially) more limited. There is also less control in how memory is managed, which might be good or bad. Any suggestions for someone deciding to go down this road?

Comment: Either of the below options seem like good solutions. If the user is concerned about memory, they can use a temporary variable on the stack for returned values and copy it to heap memory themselves. This would allow chaining to be done on the stack and then only the final value to be copied to the heap if that is what the client wants to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the memory-leak you mentioned there are a few other problems with your current system:

> - Allocating to the heap is *significantly* slower than plain stack operations.
> - Every allocation will also need to be `free()`d, meaning every instance will require at least **2** function invocations, where as just using a stack based design would require none.
> - Since memory has to be manually managed it leaves much more room for memory leaks.
> - Memory allocations can fail! A stack based system would alleviate this.
> - Using pointers would require dereferencing. This is slower than direct access, and requires more (perhaps, sloppy) sytax.

In addition to this, many compilers cache the memory used for a program's stack, and can provide signifigant improvements over the heap (which is almost never cached (if possible!))

In short, simply relying on the stack for everything would be best, not only for performance, but also maintenence and clean code. The only thing to remember is that the stack *is* finite, and it could also be easy to go crazy. Use the stack for short term data (a binary operation result in this case), and the heap for heavier long term data.

I hope this helps! :)

<sub>Note: Much of the info in this answer is thanks to @[Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424581/justin).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Allocating inside the operator isn't as convenient as it may seem.
This is mostly because you don't have garbage collection, and also because you have to worry about failed allocations.

Consider this code:

```
Vector3D *v1,*v2,*v3;
Vector3d v4 = addVectors(v1,multiplyVectors(v2,v3));
```

Seems nice.
But what happens with the vector returned from `multiplyVectors`? A memory leak.
And what happens if allocation fails? A crash in some other function.

I'd go for addition in-place:
`void addVectors(Vector3D *target, const Vector3D *src);`
This is equivalent to `target += src;`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as simple as

```
Vector3D addVectors(Vector3D a, Vector3D b) {
    Vector3D c;
    c.x = a.x + b.x;
    c.y = a.y + b.y;
    c.z = a.z + b.z;
    return c;
}
```

If the caller really needs it on the heap, he can copy it by himself.